# Importing into Access for Static Date/Time Input

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Trying to convert this simple Excel Macro:

```
Private Sub Command74_Click()
On Error Resume Next
ActiveField = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "  " & Format(Time, "hh:mm")
End Sub
```

into Access to use via a button to input Static Date AND Time into a field. Currently this is ran by a button in the Excel file, just wanting to use this in Access as well is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by "field" ...

However, if a textbox named ActiveField, do this:

```
Me!ActiveField.Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn")
```

or simply:

```
Me!ActiveField.Value = Now
```

and apply your format to the Format property of the textbox.

The textbox can be bound to a field of the table/query, the form is bound to.

Comment: Thank you Gustav, What I mean by field is: Right now in Excel the users select a cell and then press the button and the previously selected cell populates with the macro that is driven by the button. I am looking to have this same functionality in Access in a front end form view that populates the database.

Comment: Thank you again for the help Gustav, unfortunately Access does not like the {Me!ActiveField.Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn")}. There must be something with the syntax as it returns this after formatting the property {m"e!A"c"tiveFiel"d".Value = For"m"at("n\ow", dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn)"}

Comment: The Format property should only hold the format itself: dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn

Comment: No problem. Have a nice evening!